# pthread.h header problem

Tags: c++, c, visual-c++

hi
I'm doing porting from Linux to Visual C++ . When I built the coding, it shows that VC ++ doesn't know this pthread.h header. I can't comment it since there is a variable " pthread_mutex_t " in the code. What should I do ? Does VC ++ has equivalent header for it?

Kevin

Comment: Take a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2403536/pthreads-in-visual-c for similar problem.

Answer (score 5):

There is a pthreads implementation for Windows, it's called pthread-w32:

http://sourceware.org/pthreads-win32/

Comment: This is likely to make your porting job significantly easier.

Answer (score 4):

I don't think you'll find pthreads on windows unless you're using cygwin or something similar. Try the windows specific CriticalSection: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms682530(v=vs.85).aspx

Or use boost which should work on both windows and unix: http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/release/doc/html/thread/synchronization.html

Answer (score 1):

Windows has no native support for pthreads. If you want to use pthreads on Windows without significant code changes, you may want to look into [Cygwin](http://www.cygwin.com/) or one of the myriad other pthread ports.

That said, in my opinion your best move is to use an cross-platform threading library to begin with, such as [boost](http://www.boost.org/).[thread](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/release/libs/thread/doc/index.html).